# Neo4J: Query nodes where any pair of nodes are connected by a certain number of different relations?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, subgraph

How to build a Neo4J query that:

1) Will return all nodes where any pair of nodes are connected by a certain number of different relations? For example, nodes connected by 2, 3 or 5 different relations? 
So instead of a query returning connected nodes with unknown number of relations:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n, r, m;
```

How, in general case, will look query for sub-graph where any pair of nodes are connected by n > K, n = L or n < M relations?

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

To find nodes connected by a *path* of exactly 3 relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*3]->(m) RETURN n, r, m;
```

To find nodes connected by a path consisting of relationships in the range [2..5]:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*2..5]->(m) RETURN n, r, m;
```

To find nodes connected by a path of up to 5 relationships (the lower bound of 1 avoids the case where there there is no relationship, i.e., n is the same as m):

```
MATCH (n)-[r*1..5]->(m) RETURN n, r, m;
```

To find nodes connected by a path of at least 2 relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-[r*2..]->(m) RETURN n, r, m;
```

To find  pairs of nodes that are *directly connected* by, say, 3 relationships:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
WITH n, m, COLLECT(r) AS rels
WHERE SIZE(rels) = 3
RETURN n, rels, m;
```

Comment: Please help with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205781/neo4j-query-to-return-nodes-grouped-by-relation-attributes

Comment: I have accepted the answer without actually checking how it works. Unfortunaly none of these works on my Neo4J local host. All of them return 0 relations

Comment: I'm not sure why you are having problems. This is standard Cypher syntax. In fact, you can try these queries out on the default neo4j console: http://console.neo4j.org/. Do you have any relationships in your graph?

Comment: I just noticed I may have misunderstood the question 5 years ago, and have updated my answer.