# Neo4J: Query to return nodes grouped by relation attributes?

Tags: group-by, neo4j, relation

In my case, nodes are connected with one or more relations of type `similar`. This relation has two attributes `fldName` and `value`. For example:

```
(x)-[r:similar {fldName:'e-mail', value: 'name@x.y.com' }]->(y)
(x)-[r:similar {fldName:'phone', value: '123-45-67' }]->(y)
(q)-[r:similar {fldName:'e-mail', value: 'other@x.y.com' }]->(p)
(q)-[r:similar {fldName:'phone', value: '891-23-45' }]->(p)
(s)-[r:similar {fldName:'e-mail', value: 'neo@x.y.com' }]->(t)
```

Questions:

1) What is the query to return the following **separate groups** of results :

```
group 1: x,y; number of relations: 2
group 2: q,p; number of relations: 2
group 3: s,t; number of relations: 1
```

2) Is it possible to write this query without a priori knowledge the values of relation attributes?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve, I suggest you use Labels. You could populate the database as follows:

```
merge (:x)-[:similar {fldName:'e-mail', value: 'name@x.y.com' }]->(:y)
merge (:x)-[:similar {fldName:'phone', value: '123-45-67' }]->(:y)
merge (:q)-[:similar {fldName:'e-mail', value: 'other@x.y.com' }]->(:p)
merge (:q)-[:similar {fldName:'phone', value: '891-23-45' }]->(:p)
merge (:s)-[:similar {fldName:'e-mail', value: 'neo@x.y.com' }]->(:t)
```

Here you would create nodes with Labels x, y, q, p, s and t.

You can group the results with the following query:

```
MATCH (x)-[r:similar]->(y)
RETURN labels(x), labels(y), count(r) as relCount
```

See the [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=l37ss) for the result.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer! Alas I can not use labels, because I need to group relations not by single value, but by a pair of relation attributes `(fld, val)`